# in an Hasura query, is it possible to not repeat the where condition when doing an aggregate query

Tags: graphql, hasura

```
For example the following query:

 query getAttributeValues($language_code: String, $id_attribute: Int, $search: String) {
                v4_bo_v_attribute_values(
                    where: {
                        _and: [
                            { id_attribute: { _eq: $id_attribute } }
                            { _or: [{ language_code: { _eq: $language_code } }, { language_code: { _is_null: true } }] }
                            { _or: [{ attribute_value_translation: { _ilike: $search } }, { attribute_value: { _ilike: $search } }] }
                        ]
                    }
                    order_by: { attribute_value_translation: asc, attribute_value: asc }
                    limit: 100
                ) {
                    attribute_value
                    attribute_value_translation
                }
                v4_bo_v_attribute_values_aggregate(
                    where: {
                        _and: [
                            { id_attribute: { _eq: $id_attribute } }
                            { _or: [{ language_code: { _eq: $language_code } }, { language_code: { _is_null: true } }] }
                            { _or: [{ attribute_value_translation: { _ilike: $search } }, { attribute_value: { _ilike: $search } }] }
                        ]
                    }
                ) {
                    aggregate {
                        count
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use variables, even for where condition:

```
const searchQuery = search ? `%${search}%` : "%%";
const query = {       
    query: gql`
        query getAttributeValues($where: v4_bo_v_attribute_values_bool_exp) {
            v4_bo_v_attribute_values(
                where: $where
                order_by: { attribute_value_translation: asc, attribute_value: asc }
                limit: 100
            ) {
                attribute_value
                attribute_value_translation
            }
            v4_bo_v_attribute_values_aggregate(
                where: $where
            ) {
                aggregate {
                    count
                }
            }
        }
    `,
    variables: {
        where: {
            _and: [
                { id_attribute: { _eq: id_attribute } },
                { _or: [{ language_code: { _eq: tradLanguage } }, { language_code: { _is_null: true } }] },
                { _or: [{ attribute_value_translation: { _ilike: searchQuery } }, { attribute_value: { _ilike: searchQuery } }] }
            ]
        }
    }
```